# Change specific cell in dynamic tableview, Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to change a label color on a specific cell in a tableview (by code). The problem is that I want to use a dynamic cell which result in that every label in every cell will have changed they colors. Is this possible? I would really appreciate some help. This is in xcode with Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change it in `willDisplayCell`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

// put your logic here and then change the color as appropriate, for instance:

   let row = indexPath.row
   switch row {
      case 0: 
         cell.label.color = red // pseudo code
      case 2:
         cell.label.color = green // pseudo code
   // etc
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `UITableViewDataSource` you can use `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to update that cell at a specific `indexPath`, e.g.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:YourCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]
  if ([indexPath isEqual:theSpecificIndexPath]) {
    cell.label.textColor = ...;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, however do you know it in swift?:)